# How to specify HTTP method in Django HttpResponseRedirect() method

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, put, http-redirect

I need to redirect to a GET URL using *HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(url))*.
Since I am calling this redirect from a PUT method I am getting an error as *"Method "PUT" not allowed."*. Is there any way to specify the GET method?

Comment: You're misunderstanding something somewhere. A redirect is *always* a GET. It is presumably the *first* view that is raising that error.

Comment: I called the same redirect method from a 'post()' method, It worked fine. But got an error while calling from a put method

Comment: Yes, because the original view that is being called does not support PUT. This has nothing at all to do with redirects.